# A counter for: If $f+f^{-1}$ is diagonalizable then $f$ is diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, diagonalization

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and $f:V \rightarrow V$ invertible linear transformation.

Prove or disprove: If $f+f^{-1}$ is diagonalizable then $f$ is diagonalizable.

I know it's not true because I found

$A=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$

for which $A+A^{-1}$ is diagonalizable but $A$ isn't.

First of all, is my assumption about the connection between diagonalization of a matrix and a transformation correct?

If so, how can find an example for such transformation using $A$?

If not, how can I find a counter example?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you looking for? A counter-example for any dimension of $V$?

Comment: What is the link between a matrix and a linear map (transformation)? What is the definition of a diagonalisable linear map?

Comment: The linear transformation $L_A:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $L_A(v)=Av$ $\textit{is}$ your counter example. nice job.

Comment: another idea would be to look at involutions when $\text{char}\big(\mathbb F\big)=2$

Comment: Undoubtedly you mean *diagonalizable over the reals*. For $A$ is diagonalizable over $\Bbb{C}$ (as is every other real 2D rotation matrix).